# How to call InterfaceMethods from Generic Interfaces

Tags: c#

Lets say, I have a generic Interface

```cs
IWhatEver<T> : where T : ....
{
    T DoStuff(object value);
}

class Foo : IWhatEver<string> {...}
class Bar: IWhatEver<double> {...}
```

This Interface is implemented by a few classes.

How can I store instances of this interface in a list and how do I call the DoStuff function?

Something like this:

```cs
List<IWhatEver<????>> whatEvers = new List<IWhatEver<????>>();  // doesnt work...

whatEvers.Add(new Foo());
whatEvers.Add(new Bar());


var whatWillThisBe = whatEvers.Select(w => w.DoStuff(withSomeObject));
```

I believe this isnt even possible, but maybe I forgot something here?

Comment: No, it's not quite possible. You need to inherit the generic interface from a non-generic one, and that introduces another whole heap of complexity with return values for your method, et c. =)

Comment: How about using `dynamic`?

Comment: Cant use dynamic in that Context...sadly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to create a non-generic base interface and inherit generic from it

```
IWhatEver 
{
    object DoStuff(object value);
}

IWhatEver<T> : IWhatEver where T : ....
{
    new T DoStuff(object value);
}
```

You can also have a base abstract class, that inherits from IWhatEver and implements `IWhatEver.DoStuff` explicitly by calling `IWhatEver<T>.DoStuff`.

```
abstract class BaseWhatEver<T> : IWhatEver<T>
{
    abstract T DoStuff(object value);

    object IWhatEver.DoStuff(object value)
    {
          return ((IWhatEver<T>) this)DoStuff(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, was thinking about this approach, but I need to add the Interface to existing classes. Guess I will change it to Object and dont use any generics then :/